# Google Cloud Storage listbucket in App Engine behaviour

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

gcs.listbucket() method behaves in a weird fashion: sometimes it seems that the bucket is empty when it is not: calling this handler several times doen't always returns the same list: sometimes it behaves correctly and sometimes it returns an iterator with zero items.

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        bucket_name = '/my-non-empty-bucket'
        bucket_images = gcs.listbucket(bucket_name)
        self.response.write('<br> '.join([b.filename for b in bucket_images]))
```

It seems that listbucket is timed out sometimes, I don't understand.

my retry parameters:

```
my_default_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(initial_delay=0.2,
                                          max_delay=5.0,
                                          backoff_factor=2,
                                          max_retry_period=15,
                                          urlfetch_timeout=10)
gcs.set_default_retry_params(my_default_retry_params)
```

The log in app engine seems perfectly fine, no errors.
Any suggestion about how to further understand this behaviour wuld be appreciated

Comment: Have you found a fix for this? I have the same issue in my dev environment.. That said, when I deploy this code to prod, listbucket works well.

Comment: @user2779653 Firstly, gcs is eventually consistent, this means that if you just added some files in a bucket they could not be immediately present in the search. Anyway I implemented caching to not call gcs often

Comment: I am using the same code but it don't work. I have the same parameters.